# Tomcat load balacing/session replication performance with long polling

Tags: session, tomcat, cluster-computing, load-balancing

All,

I have some doubts on the performance of clustering and session management in load balanced environnent especially when dealing with long polling where continuations are suspended and saved in the server. Here are my questions:

- Does all suspended connections are replicated to all tomcat instance like other session objects ?
- Does resuming a connection/continuation on one node update connections status in other nodes automatically ?
- Does keeping open connections in all nodes impact performance ? Does load distribution still have sense ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please define connections and continuations in a Java context.

Comment: connection refers to HTTP connection and continuation refers to Apache CXF Continuation